# Prolog Question

Tags: prolog

Assume the third parameter is the result.

a( 1, [Hd | *Tl], Hd ).
a( N, [* | Tl], Elem ) :-
N > 1,
N1 is N - 1,
a( N1, Tl, Elem).

I'm trying to understand what this does....

Comment: I admit, my prolog isn't what it should be - but completely apart from that, I am missing a question here...

Answer (score 1):

It gives the Nth element of a list. You can read the definition as follows:

```
a( 1, [Hd | Tl], Hd ).
```

Hd is the 1st element of the list `[Hd | Tl]`, i.e. the list that starts with Hd, followed by the list Tl.

```
a( N, [ | Tl], Elem ) :- N > 1, N1 is N - 1, a( N1, Tl, Elem).
```

Elem is the Nth element of a list if and only if it is the `N1`th element of its tail, where `N1` is `N-1`.